# FreeMarker textarea display improper

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

I have a requirement where we have a review screen and we can see all values entered in previous screen.

Textarea is giving problem here when we have multiple lines like

eg

```
test
test
```

This gets changed to "test test" in review screen. All the return characters are replaced by spaces. 
Html code to display textarea content in review screen is:

```
<td colspan=2>
    ${description}
</td>
```

I am using Java Spring and FreeMarker. Please help me out in finding what am i doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `<pre>` tag to preserve the new lines.

```
<td colspan=2>
    <pre>${description}</pre>
</td>
```

You can style the `<pre>` element if you don't want the default monospaced font.